# What does $\vee$ mean in the context of group theory?

Tags: group-theory, notation

What does $\vee$ mean in the context of group theory? In particular, I am trying to figure understand:

[image]

Comment: It comes from lattice theory, looking at the lattice of subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $S\vee T$ denotes the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing both $S$ and $T$.